# Does the Holder inequality hold for the following?

Tags: matrices, measure-theory, lp-spaces, normed-spaces, holder-inequality

Possibly a basic question, but this is not really my area. Suppose that $f,g\in L^2(X,\mu)$ for some probability measure space $(X,\mu)$. Let us write $f=(f_1,f_2)^T:X\to \mathbb{R}^2$, and similarly for $g$. Note $fg^T$ defines a $2\times 2$ matrix. If we equip such matrices with the operator norm (or the Frobenius norm), can we say that 
$\|fg^T\|_=\int_X \|fg^T\|_{op}\, d\mu\le \|f\|_2\|g\|_2$? Or even $\le C\|f\|_2\|g\|_2$ for some constant independent of $f$ and $g$?

Obviously if it holds for one norm on the 2 by 2 matrices, then it holds for all norms since they are equivalent.

Thanks!

Edit: I think it definitely holds since this is a Bochner space with values in a finite dimensional (hence Banach) space. But a direct proof would be nice!

Comment: I assume you mean $\|fg^T\|_1$

Comment: Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly,  $$ (fg^T)_{ij} = f_i g_j.$$
Pick as a norm on $d\times d$ matrices
$$ \pmb\|(a_{ij})_{i,j}\pmb\|_1 = \sum_{i,j=1}^d |a_{ij}|.$$
Then since for each $i,j$,
$$ \int |f_i g_j| d\mu \le \|f_i\|_{L^2}\|g_j\|_{L^2},$$
Summing in $i,j$, we have
$$ \int \pmb\| fg^T\pmb\|_1 d\mu \le \sum_{i,j=1}^d \|f_i\|_{L^2}\|g_j\|_{L^2} = \sum_{i=1}^d\|f_i\|_{L^2}  \sum_{j=1}^d\|g_j\|_{L^2} \le d  \|f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2} $$
by using the inequality $\|(a_1,\dots, a_d)\|_{\ell^1} \le \sqrt{d} \|(a_1,\dots, a_d)\|_{\ell^2} $ twice.

Comment: It seems in general, for $d \times d$ matrices we have the constant $d^2$. Can this be improved on?

Comment: I suppose by normalising this can be done

Comment: @Artur wait scratch that...it should be doable but let me think

Comment: @Artur I've shaved off a factor of $d$ and this should be optimal given the choices of norms since I only used sharp inequalities

Comment: @Artur yeah the bound is attained for $f=g=(1,\dots,1)$. I'm not used to counting with matrices, and was thrown off by $ \int |f\cdot g| \le 1 \|f\|_{L^2} \|g\|_{L^2}$ :) PS its a little surprising that you know what a Bochner space is before the finite dimensional theory!

Comment: By normalising I meant by dividing the original norm you used by $d$, but I suppose it doesn't matter so much. I think the problem is it has been so long since I have worked in the f/d setting that one forgets things :)